# Link Won't Open In Safari Or InAppBrowser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, cordova

So I have been searching on here and have found tons of answers but most of them were pre 2.3 cordova when it had plist. I then found some to work with the new config.xml set up but can not get the URL to open in Safari or the InAppBrowser here is my code, and I have it white listed also have * white listed.

```
<a href="http://www.academymusicgroup.com/" onclick="window.open(this.href,'_blank'); return false;">AcademyMusicGroup</a>
```

Comment: hii sdla4ever am also facing same problem if u got solution please share with me .thanks in adv

Comment: @anilkumar07 No I havent found a solution just yet. none of the _blank _system calls seem to be working

Answer (score 0):

1)open links in safari

paste the code in your MainViewController.m file

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSURL *url = [request URL];

    // Intercept the external http requests and forward to Safari.app
    // Otherwise forward to the PhoneGap WebView
    if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"http"] || [[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"https"]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
        return NO;
    }
    else {
        return [ super webView:theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request navigationType:navigationType ];
    }
}
```

2)open links in InAppBrowser

```
function OpenLink()
                    {
                    alert(adlink); //adlink: http://www.google.com
                        var ref = window.open(adlink, '_blank', 'location=yes');//adlink is url
                        var myCallback = function() { alert(event.url); }
                        ref.addEventListener('loadstart', myCallback);
                        ref.removeEventListener('loadstart', myCallback);
                          }
```